# How to link a bool variable to a push button in c++ qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on a project that after clicking on a push button for the first time, some labels and lineedits that were hidden before, become unhide. After that, for the second time clicking on the pushbutton, I want to hide the labels again.

I have written the following code and used a bool variable, but nothing happened.

Here is my code:
dialog.h:

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
 explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
 ~Dialog();

 private slots:
  void on_pushButton_clicked();

  void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

private:
  Ui::Dialog *ui;
  bool bForButton ;
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

dialog.cpp:

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
 QDialog(parent),
 ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
  bForButton = false;
  ui->setupUi(this);
  ui->label->setVisible(false);
  ui->label_2->setVisible(false);
  ui->lineEdit->setVisible(false);
  ui->lineEdit_2->setVisible(false);
  ui->label_3->setVisible(false);
  ui->pushButton_2->setVisible(false);
 }

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
   delete ui;
}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
 bForButton = !bForButton;

 ui->label->setVisible(true);
 ui->label_2->setVisible(true);
 ui->lineEdit->setVisible(true);
 ui->lineEdit_2->setVisible(true);
 ui->label_3->setVisible(true);
 ui->pushButton_2->setVisible(true);
}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{

 double a,b,c;
 a = ui->lineEdit->text().toDouble(); //a=doublevalue of textbar1
 b = ui->lineEdit_2->text().toDouble(); //b = doublevalue of textbar2

 c=a*b;
 ui->label_3->setText(QString::number(c));
}
```

Comment: What about making your push button checkable?  `QAbstractButton::setCheckable()`.

Comment: What is supposed to happen? You're just toggling the boolean, you're not printing it, you're not using it at all

Comment: My main problem is how to use that bool problem. The code worked well (when I click on the push_button, the labels become unhide and when I click on the push_button_2, which is related to the multiply of two numbers, it works well too). The only part that does not work, is when I click on the push_button for the second time in order to hide the labels again(when I click on the push_button for the second time, all labels remain, but my goal is to hide them again)

Answer (score 0):

move the logic inside the button to an own method. then:

1. call the method in the on_click slot of the button
2. link(with signal-slots) the method for the boolean flag

Comment: Could you please explain more about the boolean part? (when I click on the push_button, the labels become unhide and when I click on the push_button_2, which is related to the multiply of two numbers, it works well too). The only part that does not work, is when I click on the push_button for the second time in order to hide the labels again(when I click on the push_button for the second time, all labels remain, but my goal is to hide them again)

Answer (score 0):

Just add these two lines into the Dialog constructor:

```
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
 QDialog(parent),
 ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
  bForButton = false;
  ui->setupUi(this);
  ui->label->setVisible(false);
  ui->label_2->setVisible(false);
  ui->lineEdit->setVisible(false);
  ui->lineEdit_2->setVisible(false);
  ui->label_3->setVisible(false);
  ui->pushButton_2->setVisible(false);

  // Add connections between signals and slots
  connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked);
  connect(ui->pushButton_2, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Dialog::on_pushButton_2_clicked);
 }
```

These will establish connection between the signals, generated by your pushbuttons and the functions, provided in Dialog class.

And then use your boolean flag to control visibility of the widgets:

```
void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
 bForButton = !bForButton;

 ui->label->setVisible(bForButton);
 ui->label_2->setVisible(bForButton);
 ui->lineEdit->setVisible(bForButton);
 ui->lineEdit_2->setVisible(bForButton);
 ui->label_3->setVisible(bForButton);
 ui->pushButton_2->setVisible(bForButton);
}
```

Comment: Actually the code works well (when I click on the push_button, the labels become unhide and when I click on the push_button_2, which is related to the multiply of two numbers, it works well too). The only part that does not work, is when I click on the push_button for the second time in order to hide the labels again(when I click on the push_button for the second time, all labels remain, but my goal is to hide them again).

Comment: Ok, the code you provided didn't have the connection part. As far as I see you inverted the flag but didn't use it. I updated my answer to show to use it. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! It works well now. I really appreciate your help.